# how can i increase the map output capacity on a node in cluster of hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am working with 3 computers in a hadoop cluster, the master has 3 GB Ram and slaves have 3 GB Ram.

the slave's map task capacity is 6, but i need more.

can i change this number? which property of machine determines map task capacity?

Comment: 6 what? Mappers running?

Comment: Also what do you mean by map task capacity?

Comment: @Sean Owen  yes,i have 6 map task running in my cluster

Answer (score 0):

The amount of memory given to the JVMs in which the map and reduce tasks run is
set by the **mapred.child.java.opts** property .

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are asking how you get it to run more than 6 mappers per worker machine. The first thing to check is the value of `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` in your cluster. It defaults to 2. If you have 3 machines, that would mean a maximum of 6 maps across the cluster -- not per worker. In any event, increase it to what you like.

But this will not make Hadoop use more mappers than it thinks is appropriate for the input. That's something you should probably leave to Hadoop.